# Issues with python data generator functions in PyTest

Tags: python, pytest

Not sure if this is a PyTest issue or Python issue or something that I'm doing wrong. I'm testing my application and have created a couple of data generator functions to speed up creation of test data. One is a parent and one a child. The Parent includes a list of child items.

If I call the parent creation method once and then append a child to it all is good. If I then call the parent method again, for the next test, the child object is then attached to this new instance. I've checked and the IDs of the parents are different so I'm a bit confused.

MRE

## hf.py

```
#helper functions

def gen_data(data_a, data_b = "one", child = []):
    return {
        "data_a": data_a,
        "data_b": data_b,
        "child": child
    }

def gen_child_data(data_1, data_2 = "two", data_3 = "three"):
    return {
        "data_1": data_1,
        "data_2": data_2,
        "data_3": data_3
    }
```

## test.py

```
from hf import *

def test_One():
    parent = gen_data("parent")
    child = gen_child_data("child")
    parent['child'].append(child)

    print(id(parent), parent)

def test_Two():
    parent = gen_data("parent two")
    print(id(parent), parent)
```

Running `pytest -s -v test.py` hits me with the following:

```
test.py::test_One 4322510784 {'data_a': 'parent', 'data_b': 'one', 'child': [{'data_1': 'child', 'data_2': 'two', 'data_3': 'three'}]}
PASSED
test.py::test_Two 4322601792 {'data_a': 'parent two', 'data_b': 'one', 'child': [{'data_1': 'child', 'data_2': 'two', 'data_3': 'three'}]}
PASSED
```

My expectation was that test_Two would be `{'data_a': 'parent two', 'data_b': 'one', 'child': []}`

Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `child` default value in your `gen_data()` function to a mutable `list`, that means that when you are appending it values in `test_One` you are modifying the `child` default value.

Set the default value to `None` and set the `child` value in the `dict` with a simple `if else`

```
def gen_data(data_a, data_b="one", child=None):
    return {
        "data_a": data_a,
        "data_b": data_b,
        "child": child if child else []
    }

def test_Two():
    parent = gen_data("parent two")
    print(id(parent), parent) # 2301583146880 {'data_a': 'parent two', 'data_b': 'one', 'child': []}
```